# How to Post Image using Byte Array[] in windows phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to post image as `byte` array. 
I have converted image to byte as using following code now I want to post it to server.

```
WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(bi);
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms, 200, 200, 0, 100);
result = ms.ToArray();
```

How can I now perform the `POST` action?

Comment: I updated my answer check it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest MIME multipart as content type. It is the content type best suited for byte array, if you ask me. One way to implement this:

```
public static async Task<string> Upload(byte[] data, string fileName, string uri)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpMultipartFormDataContent content = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent("Upload----" + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream contentStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    DataWriter dw = new DataWriter(contentStream);
    dw.WriteBytes(data);
    await dw.StoreAsync();
    await dw.FlushAsync();
    dw.DetachStream();
    contentStream.Seek(0);
    HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(contentStream);
    content.Add(streamContent, "MIMEFile", fileName);
    try
    {
        using (var message = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uri), content))
        {
            if (message.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Ok)
            {
                return String.Format("ERROR ({0})",message.StatusCode);
            }
            var result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return String.Format("ERROR ({0})", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is working very well for me. What kind of error do you get? Maybe the server-Backend does not accept MIME-Multipart...?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var imageForm = new ByteArrayContent(result, 0, result.Count());
imagenForm.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");

form.Add(imagenForm, "image", "nameholder.jpg");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("URL_here", form);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
httpClient.Dispose();
```

Hope this help's you to get idea about how to pass `byte arry to POST` into API call.

**EDIT:**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

form.Add(new StringContent(UserID), "UserID");

var imageForm = new ByteArrayContent(result, 0, result.Count());
imagenForm.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");

form.Add(imagenForm, "image", "nameholder.jpg");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("URL_here", form);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
httpClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: I updated my answer check it. Please don't tell me sir every time.

Comment: Hi Krunal I am getting following response when call above code
{"message":"Missing value at character 1","exception":"flexjson.JSONException"}

Comment: Are you calling java web service ?